# How to fix Typescript - Next.js build error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

When i build my small Typescript - Nextjs project,
occur type error like this

```
./components/Layout.tsx:3:55
Type error: Cannot find namespace 'React'.


  1 | import NavBar from "@components/NavBar";
  2 | 
> 3 | export default function Layout({children} :{children :React.ReactNode}){
    |                                                       ^
  4 |   return (
  5 |     <>
  6 |       <NavBar/>
info  - Checking validity of types .%
```

Layout.tsx is only

```
import NavBar from "@components/NavBar";

export default function Layout({children} :{children :React.ReactNode}){
  return (
    <>
      <NavBar/>
      <div>
        {children}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

and _app.tsx is

```
import '@/styles/globals.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import Layout from '@components/Layout'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from '@/store'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </Provider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

and package.json is

```
{
  "name": "bi-front",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development next dev",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=development next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production next start",
    "lint": "NODE_ENV=development next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.3",
    "@types/react-datepicker": "^4.4.2",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.24",
    "apexcharts": "^3.35.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.4.0",
    "next": "12.1.6",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.4.0",
    "react-csv-downloader": "^2.8.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-select": "^5.3.2",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.3",
    "typesafe-actions": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.5",
    "eslint": "8.18.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.6",
    "typescript": "4.7.4"
  }
}
```

The reason why i use not only _app.tsx but Layout.tsx is more simply Managing Components.

I think this is simple error,
but this is my first Typescript - Nextjs project,
so i don't know how to fix it.

Please understand that i'm not good at english,
PLEASE HELP ME :(

Comment: You could try impoting react in Layout.tsx

Answer (score 0):

You have to import React on top of your file, or Import the exact type and use it, e.g.

```
import { ReactNode } from 'react';

export default function Layout({children}: {children: ReactNode}) {

/* OR */

import React from 'react';

export default function Layout({children}: {children: React.ReactNode}) {
```